# Higher Order Function with fn as argument vs calling singleton object method

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, higher-order-functions

I am trying to remove some duplicate code using Higher Order functions.

How this is different from calling Singleton Object method?

**Sample Code:**

```
filterDFForPaymentType(filterDF, df, "Manual")
filterDFForPaymentType(filterDF, df, "Electronic")

def filterDFForPaymentType(fn: (DataFrame, String) => DataFrame, df: DataFrame, paymentType: String) {
      fn(df, paymentType)
}

def filterDF(df: DataFrame, paymentType: String): DataFrame = {
      val filteredDF = df.where(col("paymenttypecol") === paymentType)
      filteredDF
}
```

How this is different from calling the same function using a Singleton object method.

```
filterDFForPaymentType(UtilClass.filterDF(df, "Manual"))
filterDFForPaymentType(UtilClass.filterDF(df, "Electronic"))
```

I'm sure we can do much more using Higher order functions, but i don't really getting the point.

Is this something correct way to use Higher-Order functions?

Can someone give me the link for proper usage of Higher-Order functions with examples?

Comment: In this case, there is no benefit against directly using the functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filterDFForPaymentType function you have here doesn't do anything other than return the result of your other function, in this case the code can be shortened to

```
filterDF(df, "Manual")
filterDF(df, "Electronic")
def filterDF(df: DataFrame, paymentType: String): DataFrame = {
      val filteredDF = df.where(col("paymenttypecol") === paymentType)
      filteredDF
}
```

The higher order functions are useful where they implement some logic themselves (i.e. in collections the deconstruction & construction of the collection) whilst using the passed in function as part of it. In the case where the passed in function would optionally be used there could be a difference in performance.